# Why doesn't this join work with Entity Framework v4?

Tags: entity-framework

I use [Entity Framework v4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework#History) (code-only).  If I do

```
var result = from person in context.People.Include("Cars")
             select new { person, person.Houses.Count, bar, foo, etc };
```

then `result.First().Cars` is null. If I do this way, it works, but I need `Houses.Count`:

```
var result = from person in context.People.Include("Cars")
             select person;
```

It seems Entity Framework v4 doesn't work well with object initializers?

The solution for now is this:

```
var result = from person in context.People.Include("Cars").Include("Houses")
             select person;
```

But performance is ridiculous, I need to bring House row!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/527749/join-bug-at-ef4-code-only

> Hello Felipe,
>
> When Include is applied to a query, it
>   injects additional “query span”
>   information to the query that is then
>   used later on, when the query is
>   actually executed. The query span
>   information is used to internally
>   rewrite the query so that the entities
>   that can be reached through the
>   specified navigation properties are
>   also brought from the database and
>   materialized.
>
> When other query operators are applied
>   after Include, we try to preserve this
>   query span information. However, the
>   query span information specified in
>   Include will not flow over a query
>   operator that changes the result type
>   of the query.
>
> For instance, In a query like this:
>       var result = 
>           from person in context.People.Include("Cars")
>           select new { person, person.Houses.Count, bar, foo, etc };
>
> The result type is changing because of
>   the projection operation (select) at
>   the end and the final result type of
>   the query is no longer the original
>   entity type over which Include was
>   applied, so the query span information
>   is lost. A common recommendation to
>   avoid this is to always apply Include
>   at the end:
>
> ```
> var result = 
>     from person in context.People
>     select new { person, person.Houses.Count, bar, foo, etc };
> var resultWithCars =
>     result.Include("Cars");
> ```
>
> In this case, though, the outcome is
>   that Include will throw an exception
>   at runtime (as opposed to fail
>   silently) because query span cannot
>   really be applied to an anonymous
>   type.
>
> All the behavior described above is by
>   design, but since it is not possible
>   for Include to throw an exception in
>   many cases, we have found this to be a
>   common source of confusion for
>   customers.
>
> If you want to do a projection into an
>   anonymous type like this, and you want
>   to obtain the Cars property, there is
>   actually a very easy way. Simply
>   include the Cars property in the
>   projection, like this:
>
> ```
> var result = 
>     from person in context.People
>     select new { person, person.Cars, person.Houses.Count, bar,
> ```
>
> foo, etc };
>
> We are currently considering some
>   improvements to the query span API for
>   future versions that might address
>   issues like this, so your feedback is
>   very appreciated. But since we are not
>   planning improvements for the current
>   release and we keep future
>   improvements in our internal backlog,
>   I will proceed to resolve the current
>   work item.
>
> Thanks, Diego Vega Entity Framework
>   Team

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark..

Does:

```
var results = from person in context.Person
              let count = person.Houses.Count()
              select new {person, count };
```

Work?  Honestly though, I thought your first query should work.

Comment: Dont work too. Is all cases dont generated SQL to include Cars.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from person in context.People.Include("Cars")
             select new {  
                 Person = person, 
                 Cars = person.Cars,
                 HouseCount = person.Houses.Count()
             };
```

Redundant, sure, but Person.Cars will be populated, now.

Comment: Dont work too. Cars bring a list, but person.Cars return null

Comment: Something's not right, then. Can you show more code? Classes and mapping?

Comment: One thought: Test the query's `MergeOption`. It should be `AppendOnly`. `NoTracking` would certainly cause the behavior you're seeing.